# Implementing methods from a class to a interface as a linked list

Tags: java, data-structures

I have these folowing methods and I want to implement this in a class called LinkedBag

```
void replace(T oldEntry, T newEntry){}
boolean isDuplicated(T anEntry){}
void doubleBag(){}
```

1. `void replace(T oldEntry,T newEntry)` replaces any entry that is equal to `oldEntry` with the new entry `newEntry`. For example,suppose that `replace(A,D)` is called on this bag {A,B,C,A}. The resulting bag should be `{D,B,C,D}`
2. the boolean returns true if the entry `anEntry` appears more than
   one time in the bag and false otherwise. For example, calling `isDuplicated(B)` on the resulting
   bag in part 1 should return false, but `isDuplicated(D)` should return true.
3. `void doubleBag()`adds to the bag a copy of each entry that appears in the bag. For example,
   calling doubleBag() on the resulting bag in part 1 should change the bag contents to `{4’D, 2’B,  2’C}`.

Now so far I though of getting the frequency of a node and checking if the node is duplicated like:

```
 public boolean isDuplicated(T anEntry){ 
       Node currentNode =firstNode;
       int counter=0;
       while ((counter <numberOfEntries)&&(currentNode!=null))
           if(anEntry.equals(currentNode)){
               return true;
           }
       return false;
    }
```

and for the `replace` method I tried assigning values to another variables then removing them and then reassigning them again but I don't think it's right

```
   T entry=null;
        T entry1 = null;
        oldEntry=entry;
        newEntry=entry1;
        remove(oldEntry);
        entry=newEntry; 
        entry1=oldEntry;
        
        
        
        add(oldEntry);
        add(newEntry);
       System.out.println( oldEntry+" , "+newEntry );
    }
```

as for the double bag I still don't know how to do it.

Excuse me for my bad programming I am learning java new, and still learning the basics.

Comment: Does the bag really need to contain multiple copies of the same (T implements `equals` and `hashcode`).  For example, could use a data structure such as `Map<T, Integer>`, where Integer is the count (but there is actually only a single instance).  `doubleBag()` would just be going through the map and `* 2` each value of the map.

Answer (score 0):

Let's just briefly look at your `replace` method:

```
T entry = null;
T entry1 = null;
// entry and entry1 are both null
oldEntry = entry;
newEntry = entry1;
// entry, entry1, oldEntry and newEntry are all null.

remove(oldEntry); // remove null

entry = newEntry;  // overwriting null with null
entry1 = oldEntry; // same as previous statement

add(oldEntry); // add null
add(newEntry); // add null again

// print "null , null"
System.out.println(oldEntry + " , " + newEntry);
```

It's not clear what you're trying to do, but at least what's here is just a bunch of nothing. What you probably want is a little more like this:

```
// assuming oldEntry and newEntry are set somewhere and are correct, 
// and that remove and add work as expected:
remove(oldEntry);
add(newEntry);
// And you'll want to repeat this for as many duplicates as there are of oldEntry.
```

As for the `doubleBag` method, you'll want some way to walk over entries, and then duplicate them:

```
Node currentNode = head;
Node newHead = null;
Node newTail = null;
while (currentNode != null) {
  Node first = new Node(currentNode.data);
  Node second = new Node(currentNode.data);
  first.next = second;
  if (newHead != null) {
    newTail.next = first;
    newTail = second;
  } else {
    newHead = first;
    newTail = second;
  }
  currentNode = currentNode.next;
}
return newHead;
```

This code traverses the input list starting at `head`, creates two copies of the node (named `first` and `second`), links them together and appends them to a new list, which it returns at the end.

That should get you started. Also, notice how the traversal works, and see how it differs from your `isDuplicated` implementation (which currently has an infinite loop). I'll leave it to you to fix your implementation.